# What the easiest way to convert an API output to a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

AcledData = pd.read_csv("https://api.acleddata.com/acled/read?terms=accept&country=Afghanistan&date=20200315.csv", sep=',',quotechar='"', encoding ='utf-8')

print(AcledData)

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [{"status":200, success:true, last_update:117, count:500, data:[{"data_id":"6996791", iso:"4", event_id_cnty:"AFG44631", event_id_no_cnty:"44631", event_date:"2020-03-21", year:"2020", time_precision:"1", event_type:"Battles", sub_event_type:"Armed clash", actor1:"Taliban", assoc_actor_1:"", inter1:"2", actor2:"Military Forces of Afghanistan (2014-)", assoc_actor_2:"", inter2:"1", interaction:"12", region:"Caucasus and Central Asia", country:"Afghanistan", admin1:"Balkh", admin2:"Dawlat Abad", admin3:"", location:"Dawlat Abad", latitude:"36.9882", longitude:"66.8207", geo_precision:"2", source:"Xinhua; Khaama Press", source_scale:"National-International", notes:"On 21 March 2020,  12 Taliban militants including 2 commanders were killed and 5 including a commander were wounded when Afghan forces repulsed their attack in Dawlat Abad district,  Balkh.", fatalities:"12", timestamp:"1584984341", iso3:"AFG"}, {"data_id":"6997066", iso:"4".1, event_id_cnty:"AFG44667", event_id_no_cnty:"44667", event_date:"2020-03-21".1, year:"2020".1, time_precision:"1".1, event_type:"Violence against civilians", sub_event_type:"Attack", actor1:"Unidentified Armed Group (Afghanistan)", assoc_actor_1:"".1, inter1:"3", actor2:"Civilians (Afghanistan)", assoc_actor_2:"Muslim Group (Afghanistan); Teachers (Afghanistan)", inter2:"7", interaction:"37", region:"Caucasus and Central Asia".1, country:"Afghanistan".1, admin1:"Kabul", admin2:"Kabul", admin3:"".1, location:"Kabul", latitude:"34.5167", longitude:"69.1833", geo_precision:"1", source:"Pajhwok Afghan News", source_scale:"National", notes:"On 21 March 2020.1,  1 religious scholar and teacher was killed by an unknown gunmen in Kabul city.", fatalities:"1", timestamp:"1584984341".1, iso3:"AFG"}.1, {"data_id":"6997171", iso:"4".2, event_id_cnty:"AFG44715", event_id_no_cnty:"44715", event_date:"2020-03-21".2, year:"2020".2, time_precision:"2", event_type:"Battles".1, sub_event_type:"Armed clash".1, actor1:"Taliban".1, assoc_actor_1:"".2, inter1:"2".1, actor2:"Military Forces of Afghanistan (2014-)".1, assoc_actor_2:"".1, inter2:"1".1, interaction:"12".1, region:"Caucasus and Central Asia".2, country:"Afghanistan".2, admin1:"Balkh".1, admin2:"Nahri Shahi", admin3:"".2, location:"Nahri Shahi", latitude:"36.8544", longitude:"67.1800", geo_precision:"2".1, source:"Voice of Jihad", source_scale:"Other", notes:"As reported on 21 March 2020,  3 Afghan security personnel were killed and 5 were wounded following an attack by Taliban militants on a check point in Nahri Shahi district,  Balkh. Fatalities coded as 0 (VoJ reported 3 fatalities).", fatalities:"0", ...]
Index: []

Comment: Do you really think what the request returns looks like CSV data? Then, why do you feed that to `read_csv`?

Comment: @serge Ballesta - you are correct, looks more like a json output - however, I would like to convert to csv.

Comment: Do you want to convert it to a csv file or to a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query returns a Json string, but the relevant data is nested into that json. You will have to:

- read the returned string as a json object
- use the relevant part of that object to feed a dataframe

For example using `urllib.request`, you could do:

```
data = json.load(urllib.request.urlopen('https://api.acleddata.com/acled/read?terms=accept&country=Afghanistan&date=20200315.csv'))['data']
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

---

If you want to convert that to a csv file, no need for pandas, but you should use the csv module:

```
data = json.load(urllib.request.urlopen('https://api.acleddata.com/acled/read?terms=accept&country=Afghanistan&date=20200315.csv'))['data']
with open('file.csv', 'w', newline=''):
    wr = csv.DictWriter(fd, fieldnames=data[0].keys())
    _ = wr.writeheader()
    for d in data:
        _ = wr.writerow(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not csv, this is JSON

```
import pandas as pd

api = "https://api.acleddata.com/acled/read?terms=accept&country=Afghanistan&date=20200315.csv"

AcledData = pd.read_json(api)
```

the data field is then again JSON but you can use a similar technique/dataframe methods to get what you want